# How to enable OPcache in Debian?

Tags: debian, php-fpm

Just installed php5-fpm. All sources say that **apc** module has been replaced with **OPcache** and it's compiled by default but not enabled.

How can I enable this module. I can not find opcache.so file on my server

I have checked `/usr/lib/php5` and `/etc/php5` but can not find it.

```
php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u4 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 14:37:41)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can update PHP like shaun m says, or if you don't want to do that you can install zendopcache from PECL

Check for latest version [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache), this installs version 7.0.3.

Install "pecl" via php-pear

```
`sudo apt-get install -y php-pear`
```

Install build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential php5-dev
```

Install Zend OpCache

```
sudo pecl install zendopcache-7.0.3
```

Find the location of opcache.so

```
sudo find / -name 'opcache.so'
```

Mine is

```
/usr/lib/php5/20100525/opcache.so
```

Now create opcache.ini

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini
```

Add this info

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/opcache.so # File path from above
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Now create a symlink for the conf file

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/20-opcache.ini
```

Restart services

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Confirm install

```
php -v
```

It should give mention of

```
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Then (optionally) finish by cleaning up

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge build-essential php5-dev
```

[Reference](http://fideloper.com/install-zend-opcache)

Answer (score 2):

OPCache is only enabled and compiled in by default in the new PHP 5.5, not the 5.4 that comes with Wheezy. If you'd like to use OPCache and PHP 5.5 in Debian, you'll have to add the dotdeb repos (see below) and install from there.

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all 
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install APC whit pecl

```
pecl install apc
```

php-pear and php-dev are needed to install it.

Or you can install whit apt-get

```
apt-get install php5-apc
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jeremy Davis' answer...

In case your /tmp directory is mounted as "noexec" (preventing execution of scripts written there, which is common on public-facing servers), the pecl install command will fail like this:

```
shtool at '/tmp/pear/temp/zendopcache/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.
```

To avoid this, you can remount the /tmp partition as exec, then pecl install, hen remount as noexec, like this:

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
pecl install zendopcache
mount -o remount,noexec /tmp
```

After checking with our sysadmin that this was alright, I tried it on a server in production and it worked perfectly fine (you will have to restart your PHP profcess (be it FPM or an Apache module) after that anyway, so probably not a good idea on a very high load server, but for mildly used public servrs, the whole process seems to work just fine.